# Is it possible to fill particular portion between given start & end angle in pie chart in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, chart.js

I want a circular chart where i can pass start angle and end angle and the portion between then get filled with some color. Is it possible in chart.js pie chart? And not then is there any other chart which is giving such kind of functionality?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Angle doesn't mean much. Although you can calculate according to angle value with 360 then in the series you can pass the points using high chart. You can refer http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/ link

Comment: I have made simple function showing how you can make chart similar to your requirements in Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/46vfygqu/

Comment: Hi, @GrzegorzBlachliński !! Thanks a lot for sharing same function which i want. But is it possible there to fill portion between [345,105] angle?

Comment: Yes, you can try to use two fields [345,360] and [0,105] in this case. Look into my example: http://jsfiddle.net/46vfygqu/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help. It solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Highcharts pie chart and wrote custom function that will 'fill' your chart depending on start angle and end angle you will pass in your point.

Your data may look like that:

```
  data: [{
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 105,
    color: 'green'
  }, {
    startAngle: 315,
    endAngle: 360,
    color: 'green'
  }]
```

And your custom function may be similar to this function:

```
function(chart) {
    var series = chart.series[0],
      start = series.data[0].startAngle,
      updatedData = [start],
      pointBetween,
      point;
    Highcharts.each(series.data, function(p) {
      pointBetween = p.startAngle - start;
      if (pointBetween !== 0) {
        updatedData.push({
          y: p.startAngle - start
        });
      }
      point = {
        color: p.color,
        y: p.endAngle - p.startAngle
      }
      updatedData.push(point);
      start = p.endAngle;
    });
    updatedData.push({
      y: 360 - start
    })
    series.setData(updatedData);
  }
```

I have made very simple example showing how your chart may look with this function:

http://jsfiddle.net/46vfygqu/